# No suitable method found for get(Book)

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on `displayBooksFromAuthor()` which will display authors specified by user input. I am trying to do this without getter and setter methods for the element "author". Sorry if this has been posted before, but I couldn't find any info on my situation. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BookCollection
{
    public ArrayList<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
/**
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int counter = 0;
    String name;

    public BookCollection() throws IOException
    {
        String oneLine;
        Scanner fileScan, dataScan;
        String isbn, author, area;
        int pages;
        Book oneBook;

        fileScan = new Scanner(new File("booksTwo.txt"));
        while(fileScan.hasNext())
        {
            oneLine = fileScan.nextLine();
            dataScan = new Scanner(oneLine);
            isbn = dataScan.next();
            author = dataScan.next();
            area = dataScan.next();
            pages = dataScan.nextInt();
            oneBook = new Book(isbn, author, area, pages);
            bookList.add (counter, oneBook);
            counter++;
        }
    }**/

    public BookCollection(){
    bookList.add(new Book("1001-01-141514", "Letones", "CS", 611));
    bookList.add(new Book("1002-01-141424", "Lewis", "CS", 477));
    bookList.add(new Book("1003-01-141434", "Smith", "MATH", 698));
    bookList.add(new Book("1004-01-141444", "Smith", "CS", 617));
    bookList.add(new Book("1005-01-141454", "Brown", "CHEM", 326));
    bookList.add(new Book("1006-01-141464", "Smith", "BIO", 127));
    bookList.add(new Book("1007-01-141474", "Sanket", "CS", 998));
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s = "\n All Books in the store \n\n";
        for(int i = 0; i <bookList.size(); i++)
            s += bookList.get(i).toString() + "\n";
        return "" + s;
    }

    public void displayLongBooks()
    {
        System.out.println("LONG BOOKS \n");
        for (Book b: bookList)
        {
            if (b.isLong())
                System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author)
    {
        for(Book b: bookList)
        {
            if (bookList.get(b) == author);   //error here
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: `if(bookList.get(b).author.equals(author)) {...}`

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)), or better yet, the error message. It's pretty self-explanatory. `get` takes an integer. You're passing it a `Book`. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Whenever pressing the compile button a get a compile error that states

Comment: oh, hah. right. `if(b.author.equals(author))` my mistake, did not notice the enhanced for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this piece of code:

```
/*
   Your original code:
 */
public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author)
{
    for(Book b: bookList)
    {
        if (bookList.get(b) == author); // WRONG
        // 1. You can't compare strings with ==
        // 2. Why do you put an ending ; there? If you leave it there
        //    the if statement is useless
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

You already have a book `b` pulled from the `bookList` object, so all you need to do is work with `b`. Also, you can't compare strings with `==`; either use [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
/*
   Corrected code:
 */
public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author) {
    for(Book b : bookList) {
        if(b.author.equals(author))
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use: [`.equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) or [`.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) or [`.compareToIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29):

- `if(b.author.equalsIgnoreCase(author)){/*Code if true*/}`
- `if(b.author.compareTo(author) == 0) {/*Code if true*/}`
- `if(b.author.compareToIgnoreCase(author) == 0) {/*Code if true*/}`

---

Also, AFAIK it's a better practice to keep object attributes private, and use `getXXX()` methods to read them. So, in your `Book` class, you should write something like this:

```
public class Book {
    // Attributes
    private String author
    // More attributes
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Book(/*Constructor arguments*/) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return this.author;
    }
    // More code for class Book
}
```

and in your `displayBooksFromAuthor()` method:

```
public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author) {
    for(Book b : bookList) {
        if(b.getAuthor().equals(author))
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shekhar and Barranka thank you very much. I got it to print right. I didn't notice the semi-colon at the end of the for statement.

Comment: @Matt Happy to help. By the way, if you find this (these) answer(s) useful, upvote it (them) and/or accept it (one of them).

Comment: Gotcha guys. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Error is at line 4 of the below method

```
public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author)
{
    for(Book b: bookList)
    {
        if (bookList.get(b) == author);   // error is here
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

You should simply compare using `b.author.equals(author)` for comparing the author name. And,you must use `equals()` method for comparing Strings! Also **don't place a semi-colon`(;)` at the end of the if-statement,unless needed**. It'll always print the next line then.

Correct it as :-

```
public void displayBooksFromAuthor(String author)
{
    for(Book b: bookList)
    {
        if (b.author.equals(author))
            System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, wow thanks for the help. After the equals method checks the author should i set a new variable before printing out "b"? because when printing b after the if statement all that prints is my  book arraylist

Comment: @Matt-There is a `;` in the last of if-statement. Remove that and it'll work fine,check my edit with bold statement.